Vercel CRON job is not automatically triggered, works with manual trigger through settings
I have a project that is still using Next 13 with the pages router. Project is hosted on Vercel and I use the Hobby Plan. As warned by Vercel:

To stream responses you must use Route Handlers in the App Router, even if the rest of your app uses the Pages Router.

So I have a folder inside the src folder called app and the route.ts file in app/api/cron/.
Running the Cron job manually through the Cron settings works, but it just wont trigger automatically. I am aware that for the Hobby plan the Cron may run within an hour time range of the set time. I cannot figure out why it won't run automatically within the allotted time, I do not see any error logs either during this period for the request path.
vercel.json:
{
  "crons": [
    {
      "path": "/api/cron",
      "schedule": "0 13 * * *"
    }
  ]
}

The script is copy pasted from vercel's website
cron.ts:
export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";

export function GET(request: Request) {
  return new Response(`Cron has ran successfully`);
}

I have also tried upgrading to Next 14/15 and it still won't run automatically
If you have ever encountered this issue and may have a solution please share.
